# VLC: network stream over RTSP: can I use more aggressive buffering?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, vlc-media-player, streaming

I can watch my RTSP stream with *VLC* almost perfectly.

The stream is live, transcoded from h264 to h265 by *ffmpeg*.

My only concern is that the stream is occasionally (depends on many factors, but at least once per 10 second) audio stutters while video plays, sometimes video stutters while audio plays, and sometimes both are stuck, having then hard time to get back in shape.

I did a little test: save the transcoded stream to mp4 *locally*: it's perfect, no stuttering. However I realized something at the end of this conversion:

```
video:22144kB audio:1469kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:2kB muxing overhead: 0.257809%
x265 [info]: frame I:      8, Avg QP:26.63  kb/s: 22492.08
x265 [info]: frame P:    461, Avg QP:28.36  kb/s: 6194.07
x265 [info]: frame B:   1390, Avg QP:31.72  kb/s: 1077.79
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 0.2% 1.5% 0.0% 98.3%

encoded 1859 frames in 74.47s (24.96 fps), 2438.69 kb/s, Avg QP:30.87
```

This was a not-too-long sample (75s), and it contained 8 *I-frames*, so it's matching with my experiment on the VLC side: stuttering once per 10s, if this is caused by I-frames.

And indeed, network bandwidth between VLC and transcoded stream has a maximum throughput of 20MBps, but it needs many seconds (~5) to reach that, so it's not instantly available.

This of course can cause stuttering. I tried to increase VLC's `:network-caching=10000`, but it's not causing any noticable improvements (almost better to use lower values, like 500 for some weird reason).

How can I convince VLC to really use the buffer on network stream? I.e. setting a 10s buffer: VLC shall wait first 10s before starts playback, then it should start playback from buffer's begin, while it should keep receiving to buffer's end. It seems not the case with `network-caching`, or my VLC (3.0.17.4, Windows 10) contains a bug here.